# Linux and Intel 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ link always down

Tags: linux, networking, network-adapter, slackware

I have HP ProLiant dl360 gen 9, when server starts i have link on Intel 82599ES.
 After start linux (Slackware 14.2 kernel 4.4.19) link is down (something like spf power is down?).
How can I fix it?

```
# lspci | grep Network
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)

# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Speed: Unknown!
        Duplex: Unknown! (255)
        Port: FIBRE
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: external
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Supports Wake-on: umbg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: no

# ethtool -i  eth0
driver: ixgbe
version: 4.2.1-k
firmware-version: 0x80000887
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:04:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no

# lsmod |grep -E 'ixgbe|mdio|igb|ioat|dca'
ixgbe                 221749  0
vxlan                  34494  1 ixgbe
ptp                    12164  2 tg3,ixgbe
mdio                    3973  1 ixgbe
ioatdma                33129  0
dca                     6585  2 ixgbe,ioatdma
hwmon                   4199  4 tg3,ixgbe,coretemp,acpi_power_meter

# ethtool -m  eth0
        Identifier                                : 0x03 (SFP)
        Extended identifier                       : 0x04 (GBIC/SFP defined by 2-wire interface ID)
        Connector                                 : 0x07 (LC)
        Transceiver codes                         : 0x10 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
        Transceiver type                          : 10G Ethernet: 10G Base-SR
        Encoding                                  : 0x06 (64B/66B)
        BR, Nominal                               : 10300MBd
        Rate identifier                           : 0x00 (unspecified)
        Length (SMF,km)                           : 0km
        Length (SMF)                              : 0m
        Length (50um)                             : 80m
        Length (62.5um)                           : 30m
        Length (Copper)                           : 0m
        Length (OM3)                              : 300m
        Laser wavelength                          : 850nm
        Vendor name                               : FINISAR CORP.
        Vendor OUI                                : 00:90:65
        Vendor PN                                 : FTLX8571D3BCL-HP
        Vendor rev                                : A
        Option values                             : 0x00 0x1a
        Option                                    : RX_LOS implemented
        Option                                    : TX_FAULT implemented
        Option                                    : TX_DISABLE implemented
        BR margin, max                            : 0%
        BR margin, min                            : 0%
        Vendor SN                                 : MVA0TLN
        Date code                                 : 16031211
        Optical diagnostics support               : Yes
        Laser bias current                        : 0.000 mA
        Laser output power                        : 0.0062 mW / -22.08 dBm
        Receiver signal average optical power     : 0.0000 mW / -inf dBm
        Module temperature                        : 28.81 degrees C / 83.86 degrees F
        Module voltage                            : 3.3293 V
        Alarm/warning flags implemented           : Yes
        Laser bias current high alarm             : Off
        Laser bias current low alarm              : On
        Laser bias current high warning           : Off
        Laser bias current low warning            : On
        Laser output power high alarm             : Off
        Laser output power low alarm              : On
        Laser output power high warning           : Off
        Laser output power low warning            : On
        Module temperature high alarm             : Off
        Module temperature low alarm              : Off
        Module temperature high warning           : Off
        Module temperature low warning            : Off
        Module voltage high alarm                 : Off
        Module voltage low alarm                  : Off
        Module voltage high warning               : Off
        Module voltage low warning                : Off
        Laser rx power high alarm                 : Off
        Laser rx power low alarm                  : On
        Laser rx power high warning               : Off
        Laser rx power low warning                : On
        Laser bias current high alarm threshold   : 13.200 mA
        Laser bias current low alarm threshold    : 4.000 mA
        Laser bias current high warning threshold : 12.600 mA
        Laser bias current low warning threshold  : 5.000 mA
        Laser output power high alarm threshold   : 1.0000 mW / 0.00 dBm
        Laser output power low alarm threshold    : 0.2512 mW / -6.00 dBm
        Laser output power high warning threshold : 0.7943 mW / -1.00 dBm
        Laser output power low warning threshold  : 0.3162 mW / -5.00 dBm
        Module temperature high alarm threshold   : 78.00 degrees C / 172.40 degrees F
        Module temperature low alarm threshold    : -13.00 degrees C / 8.60 degrees F
        Module temperature high warning threshold : 73.00 degrees C / 163.40 degrees F
        Module temperature low warning threshold  : -8.00 degrees C / 17.60 degrees F
        Module voltage high alarm threshold       : 3.7000 V
        Module voltage low alarm threshold        : 2.9000 V
        Module voltage high warning threshold     : 3.6000 V
        Module voltage low warning threshold      : 3.0000 V
        Laser rx power high alarm threshold       : 1.0000 mW / 0.00 dBm
        Laser rx power low alarm threshold        : 0.0100 mW / -20.00 dBm
        Laser rx power high warning threshold     : 0.7943 mW / -1.00 dBm
        Laser rx power low warning threshold      : 0.0158 mW / -18.01 dBm
```